Sign in With Solana - On an SSL protected website. Nonce is not necessary, right?
I created an example repository on how to build a website that features sign-in-with-solana. I want to be extra sure that I am getting this right: Because we transmit the signed auth message over SSL, the nonce is unnecessary. It should be akin to sending the unhashed password in a normal password based login system.
Am I missing something? Why is the nonce even part of the standard?
(I thought about it for a while and I have a hard time to come up with a situation in which it could be helpful)
Thank you very much for your help!
login.ts - siws message verification in the backend 
video description of the code base
